# Rails is giving me a file.js isn't precompiled error after deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm using a simple include directly in an erb :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "file.js" %>
```

I simply took code which was in one of my documents inside script tags and moved it out into this file and placed it in app/assets/javascripts/file.js.  Do I have to list this file somewhere?  I do not want it included on every page, just certain pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( file.js )
```

Or

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Also make sure you got this in your capistrano recipe"

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```